# Connect to TCP address in terminal

Tags: qt, ubuntu, server, terminal

How can i connect to the port that is listening in Ubuntu terminal?

I have a server running, which is written in Qt, which opens a port for listening. How can I connect to it through the Ubuntu terminal? I don't want to write a separate client for program testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you might want to use **telnet** or **nc(netcat)**.

- **[Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet)**

  The telnet command is a simple way to establish a TCP connection to a remote server. Here's how you can use it:

  ```
  telnet <server-ip> <port>
  ```
- Using **[nc(Netcat)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)**

  The nc (netcat) command is a versatile networking utility that can be used for various purposes, including creating TCP and UDP connections. Here's how you can use it:

  ```
  nc <server-ip> <port>
  ```

Remember to replace the server-ip and port with your own.